# Can AWS help to improve website speed due to bad database design & coding?

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services

I really concern about this question that can AWS help to improve website speed due to bad database design (MySQL) & coding (PHP) ?

Comment: The best way to fix problems with bad database design is good database design

Comment: AWS cannot fix a bad design. The best approach is to write functional tests around your app, so that you have test automation in place, and then refactor it, including the database changes you need.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very broad question, and the response need many data of the application, but, in general terms, the answer is no.

No system can fix a bad application design or a bad data model design. You can increase the performance of the system and the capacity of the hardware, and it work until certain limit, but is not a good solution (really is not a solution in anyway).

If you have a problem in the application, you need to change the application, not the system.

Comment: Thanks Deniel, but why some developers or company is looking for third party solution to handle the badly design databases and coding because its really not good.

Comment: Personally i never prefer such kind of solutions because it feels like a question mark on my skills.